# Filter mongodb cursor in a subfield of document

Tags: java, mongodb, cursor

I trying to perform a query in my mongo database using java code. I want to filter the result of the query using cursor. Basically I want to filter the cursor results two times. My query return some documents, and I want to filter them based on a field of document and a sub-field of the first field. For example:

```
 DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
 while(cursor.hasNext()) {
       BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
        System.out.println(obj.getString("images")); 
}
```

Return the image field from all quered documents. What should I do if I want to return the field "link" which is a subfield of field "images"? I tried `obj.getString("images").getString("link")`, however it doesn't work. Images is an array with three fields the first one is the filed "link". When the above return is the following: `[ { "link" : "http://distilleryimage1.ak.instagram.com/fc7c5_7.jpg" , "phash" : "01000010101000101010111101" , "persons" : 1}]` . I want to return just the first field link.

Comment: Sample documents has several fields, one of them is called "images". When I use the code posted in my question it return the field "images". I want to perform a second depth filtering to subfield "link".

Comment: I know what to do with c#, but in java this may help:     var  images = (ArrayList<BasicDBObject>)obj.get("images");
    for(BasicDBObject image: images){ var link = image.getString("link") }

Comment: What exactly is var variable? Is it a list?

Comment: Yes, just change var to ArrayList<BasicDBObject> and place an answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get images as ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<BasicDBObject> images = (ArrayList<BasicDBObject>)obj.get("images"); 
for(BasicDBObject image: images)
{
     String link = image.getString("link");
     .......
}
```